# Is it possible to use Steam to download game files while booted in Linux?

Tags: windows, dual-boot, steam

First of all, I am not interested in actually **playing** the games while running Linux.  Read on :)

I dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 10.  I spend the majority of my time in Linux but keep Windows around only for gaming.  And since I live in a rural area with very slow internet speeds, I would like to have Steam download my Windows games while I'm using linux.

It would be such a waste of time to boot up Windows just to keep it there for 14 hours, downloading a game while I can't do any of my normal computing tasks.

I know this might be possible by installing the Windows Steam client and running with Wine (and then copying the files to my Windows partition, but wondered if there might be a more elegant solution?

Has this been done before and does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe a VM with a shared disk with the primary windows install?  Otherwise the Linux/Wine Steam instance will download to a location that the windows install wouldn't see...

Comment: Right.  I would manually copy the appropriate files to my Windows partition after they've been downloaded.  I've tried running with Wine but can't get Steam installed.

Answer (score 1):

Best option apart from VM is you can install Steam on linux and then you can download the whole game, yes the linux version.

Now steam provides the option to backup your game, Take backup of game you want.

Bootup in windows, there is again option to restore games from backup. Restore the game.

This will work only for games which are supported on linux.

Comment: You can also use steamcmd to download games even if they do not have native Linux support (seemingly).

Comment: @DopeGhoti Nice point out! I myself wasn't aware of this.

Comment: For headless Linux game servers, steamcmd is a godsend.

Answer (score 1):

Try [SteamCMD](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamCMD#Linux).

I'm only just setting this up for myself now so unfortunately I can't give much help.